# Javascript-How to implement target=_blank in a simple link

Tags: javascript, html, target

So, this is my code:

`function link1()
{
window.location.href="Example";
}`

How do i achieve the _blank function in JS?

Cheers

(Note: I am not using a library, nor am i intending to atm)

Comment: @isherwood: No, this doesn't relate to attributes. That's just the OP's title steering you off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

window.open will do the trick.

```
function link1()
{ 
   window.open("http://www.example.com");
}
```

Comment: Indeed. Provided this is called during the processing of a user-initiated event (otherwise, the pop-up blocker will do its job).